# How can I remove the screen refresh rate overlay?

Tags: 20.04, display

I somehow caused a strange issue with one of my monitors.  This happened with the previous kernel that I updated to yesterday (4/4/2021).  The issue is that there is an overlay of yellow numbers that shows the refresh rate of one of my monitors.  It showed up when I was messing with `cvt` / `xrandr` trying to get the proper monitor resolution to work (the installed kernel broke 1080p through USB-C / DP / HDMI).

The monitor resolution issue has gone away with the new kernel release (on 4/5/2021), but the refresh rate overlay is still present.  I'd post a screenshot, but the overlay doesn't capture in the screenshot.

Does anyone have any idea where this overly came from and how can I remove it?

Comment: Could it originate from the monitor's own OSD menu that you activated somehow?

Comment: Well don't I feel silly. That's exactly what it was.  Thanks for the tip